# How do I use bower in a typical .NET / Visual Studio workflow?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, bower

I'm unhappy how nuget handles client-side packages, so I want to try bower, [as per the process described here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx). I want the tool to fit into my workflow, not vice versa.

Note that what I'm interested in is *bower* - I just want client-side package manager, not those grunt/gulp build tools.

What I've done:

- Everything in that post. I'm on VS2013 Update 4, I installed those 3 extensions, and the windows version of nodejs, and then bower.

What I want to do, is more or less a .NET/VS-ish worflow:

1. When I install some package, it pulls the entire repo! I only want the sort of files you'd get in a nuget package, e.g. `foo.js`, `foo.min.js`, `foo.css`, `foo.min.css` and webfonts.
2. I want those files to go to the right places, so scripts to `~/scripts/lib`, stylesheets to `~/styles/lib` and fonts to `~/fonts`. Right now it's just dumping everything in `bower_components` which is no better than what nuget does for me.
3. I'd like to rename those files to the way we do it in the .NET world, so `foo-2.0.1.js` and `foo-2.0.1.min.js`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

1. Apparently Bower pulls down all the junk, and there's nothing you can do about it! Seems silly to me coming from a nuget background, but that's how it works in this tool.
2. I moved the files from the `bower_components` directory, to the appropriate places, using a javascript-based build tool. I used "Gulp", which has tooling support in VS2013-Update3 onwards.
3. I didn't change the filenames. The node stack seems to work better that way.

Comment: It would be great if you could point us towards more thorough documentaiton. Perhaps a blog post if you have a blog?

Comment: @DamianPowell Nope sorry no blog... The trick is to just use gulp to move the files to your preferred directory. They are downloaded into `solutionroot\bower_components`, and I wanted them in `solutionroot\mymvcproject\scripts\..` etc., so you use a gulp task to move those files to the target directory. Just find an example of a gulp task which copies files, and adapt it. And do yourself a favor and ignore "grunt", it's older and not worth the effort, use "gulp" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @h_bob. I haven't used gulp before but I'll look into it.

Comment: @DamianPowell For us .NET types, put it like this: think of npm as nuget (ie it downloads client-side libraries), and think of gulp as msbuild (ie it runs a makefile/.csproj).

Comment: @DamianPowell [check this out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/02/17/using-bower-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx)